# ASP.NET MVC - Updating a record

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im trying to perform update of some records.
When im calling a create action after i insert the record i take out some of the records and change a non-primary key value. Then i call UpdateModel on each to try to save them.
But i get error: The model of type "" was not successfully updated.
If i check ModelState i see that the id value (wich is PK and IDENTITY fails -> A value is required.). The value at id isnt there.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess what the reason might be, but if you trigger the whole thing from a form, I would do "view source" of the html form and make sure your id is there (in a hidden field?). Maybe you forgot to set the id property in your viewmodel before passing it to the view?

That's my best guess without seeing some sample code :)